# Firebase Android showing error in dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am tryig to create a real time database using Firebase. I have followed the principles but showing errors.

my build.gradle app is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashik.project"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.dakatso:livebutton:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my build.gradle project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Showing error in console:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
  >   Could not resolve com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+.
  >    Required by:
  >        project:app:unspecified
  >   Could not resolve com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+.
  >   Failed to list versions for com.firebase:firebase-client-android.
  >   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/firebase/firebase-client-android/maven-metadata.xml.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/firebase/firebase-client-android/maven-metadata.xml'.
  >   jcenter.bintray.com
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

how can i solve this please help......

Comment: It seems to me that gradle cant recognize this library 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'.. Is it really necessary? If not, try removing it's dependency to see if the build succeeds

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
```

with

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```

or

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're half using Firebase 2.x (com.firebase...) and half using Firebase 3.x (com.google.firebase...

Maybe those two are conflicting and causing errors?

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android should help you switch over.